# Suitability of Meditation Types

Tags: meditation-practicalities, meditation-recommendation

I return to this site after a long absence due to various causes.

My current question is whether some meditations are more suited to certain contexts than others, for example:

1. Would mindfulness of breathing be as easy as other meditations on public transport?
2. Would mindfulness of sight be more appropriate in such a context?
3. Is mindfulness of breathing suitable to walking, or is it preferable to practice mindfulness of stepping and so on?

I am mainly asking this because my formal meditation is almost impossible, as I live at home and noises are continuously occurring. I'm specifically talking about television noises, or discussions, which in addition to being loud also distract from my practice. Thus, I search for other situations to meditate in, like transport and walking.

Answer (score 1):

> **Would mindfulness of breathing be as easy as other meditations on public transport?**

Mindfulness with breathing is most suitable for public transport.

> **Would mindfulness of sight be more appropriate in such a context?**

Both should be practised. When there is nothing necessary to look at, practise anapanasati. When there is something necessary to look at, have mindfulness & wisdom at sense contact.

> **Is mindfulness of breathing suitable to walking, or is it preferable to practice mindfulness of stepping and so on?**

Mindfulness with breathing is suitable to formal walking, i.e., when walking back & forth on a defined path or when walking on a clear path/road (with no obstacles to trip on). However, it requires skill to practise it.

> **I am mainly asking this because my formal meditation is almost impossible, as I live at home and noises are continuously occurring.
>   I'm specifically talking about television noises, or discussions,
>   which in addition to being loud also distract from my practice.**

You should still try to practise anapanasati at home (although it is difficult to do with eyes closed in the presence of others but can be done with eyes open).

Answer (score 0):

May I direct you to the following article on Mahasati Meditation:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahasati_meditation

"Also known as Dynamic Meditation, Mahasati Meditation is a form of mindfulness meditation. It is a technique developed by Thai Buddhist reformist Luangpor Teean Cittasubho. Mahasati Meditation uses movement of the body to generate self-awareness and is a powerful tool for self-realization."

At the end of the day, only through trial and error and we can then evaluate what works best. Whatever works best is the way to go.

Comment: I suggest to attempt to answer the question directly. This is not an evangelical site for advertising our favourite gurus.

Comment: Thanks. I was merely hoping to point a suitable direction for the poster to do some more reading. As I myself is in the process of studying Mahasati Meditation, however not so confident in elaborating it just yet. Still, suggestions accepted.